# NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate fired instead of NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a NSFetchedResultsController initiated in the following way:

```
NSEntityDescription *myEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:myEntity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"wasDeleted == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor, nil]];

myFetchedResults = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
myFetchedResults.delegate = self;
[myFetchedResults performFetch:nil];
```

Some facts:

- wasDeleted is an NSNumber property (BOOL) of MyEntity
- If I update this property to `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate calls didChangeObject but firing **NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate** instead of **NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete**.
- However, if I pop the view and init again the fetched results controller, the object is not there anymore, showing that `[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"wasDeleted == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]];` works.
- After this NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate, when cellForRow is called, I print wasDeleted and it's set to YES.

What can be wrong here?

(In other words, NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete can be called if the object still exists on the context however doesn't fit the predicate?)

Comment: Why are you using a wasDeleted property instead of just deleting the object? `NSManagedObject` already has a property called isDeleted in case you need to track this in between saves

Comment: The problem, as I comment in the question, is that if the deletion was committed offline, I need to know so I can update the delete to the server when the user gets the connection. It is like a soft delete, and when I confirm the deletion in the server, I do the real deletion.

Comment: I've built a test app using the exact same fetch request and when I change `wasDeleted` to TRUE I do in fact see a `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` notification. Can you post the code where you make the wasDeleted change?

Comment: @ChrisH the strange is that, when I receive the `changeUpdate`, i check the object, and the property is TRUE also... So it is saving correctly...

Comment: Are you doing anything special in the MyEntity class? Overriding accessor methods for example? Does this problem occur if you create a new property and make that the subject of the predicate?

Comment: @NatanR.: I cannot reproduce that behaviour. I have created a FRC with the same "wasDeleted = NO" predicate as yours. Setting `wasDeleted = YES` fires a NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete event. Is there anything special in your code that might be relevant? Is the property changed in the main context or in a separate background context?

Comment: Thanks for updating, Martin. I don't think there is any special remark. The property is changed in the background, but the main thread MOC gets the notification and saves the change (I check the property in the delegate method fired and it's YES). How exactly did you set the predicate?

Comment: @NatanR.: `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"wasDeleted = %@", @(NO)]; fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;`, that is the same as your code, only using the new "modern" syntax `@(NO)` (but that is irrelevant here).

Comment: @NatanR.: What happens if you set `wasDeleted = NO` for an object again. Does that fire a `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` event? (It does in my test app.)

Comment: Have you posted your actual code? `[fetchRequest myEntity];` does not look right.

Comment: @MartinR I think that was a typo. I cut and pasted his code into a new project (fixing that typo) and I always get the `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` notification. Without more code we can only speculate, but I'm wondering whether the same managed object is not being modified in different contexts/threads.

Comment: @ChrisH: Yes, same for me. Even with modification in a separate context and merging into the main context I could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, guys. Edited and fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Of course `changeUpdate` and not `changeDelete`. You only updated a value and not deleted the whole item. If you delete the item from your db then it will call `changeDelete`. And it is not shown after the new init because you table is filtering based on this attribute.

You will need to listen for `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` and check there if the attribute `wasDeleted` is changed. If so update your table view to your needs, eg. delete the specific row.

Comment: relikd, not of course `changeUpdate`, because this specific change should remove the object from the `NSFRC`. If you update a object property, and this  change should remove the object, I should receive `changeDelete`. The strange is the following: in one hand, if I do performFetch: again, the object is not there anymore; in other hand, the change called is `changeUpdate`.

Comment: In other words, NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete can be called if the object still exists on the context however doesn't fit the predicate?

Comment: was it really deleted from your sqlite db? I think the `changeDelete` is only called when its deleted from db and not from filtered request (predicate). In my apps I used the `changeUpdate` to determine what was changed and if so delete the cell manually from table view and reload data afterwards.

Comment: This answer does not seem plausible to me. The object is *updated*, but due to that update it is *deleted* from the FRC result set. In my experience, this causes a NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete notification. If deleting a table view row in response to a NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate notification were really necessary, then 1) all the FRC boilerplate code at Apple and other resources would be incomplete, and 2) the FRC index path and the table view index path would be out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing in my app and have noticed that the `-controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:newIndexPath` delegate first gets called with a change type of `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` followed by a second call with a change type of `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate`.

The `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` might be expected behaviour, but what's left unexplained is why the first call with `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` is missing.  Can you confirm you're handling this case correctly?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. In the `changeUpdate` I check for the property, and it was successfully saved correctly, and should not be there...

Answer (score 1):

I had the *exact same* issue as you.

Do not use `wasDeleted` as your property name. You should not use variations of `deleted` when dealing with your CoreData objects.

I renamed my property to `hidden`, and used that for the predicate. Everything worked as you would expect.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, changing the name of the property didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Are you using a transient property?  Could that play a role?

Comment: It is not a transient property.

Comment: wasDeleted as a property name works fine. Using deleted is what gave me this problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4056756/88164