# XCode 9.0: App crashes on delete table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITable. I was able to successfully implement editing for the table so that you could swipe to delete cells. However, since updating my Xcode, my app crashes when I swipe to delete.

```
Thread 1
  2 - [ViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:]
  3 - [ViewController controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPathforChangeType:newIndexPath];
  16 - [ViewController tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAndIndexPath];
```

Looking at the thread above, `16` causes a breakpoint at the if clause checking for an error after saving the context for the core data object. Then line 3 shows that NSFetchRequestUpdate was fired instead of NSFetchRequestDelete - so the app tries to configure the cell instead of delete it.  **Why would this be happening after I updated my xCode? This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690681/nsfetchedresultschangeupdate-fired-instead-of-nsfetchedresultschangedelete) has a similar issue, but there is no verified answer.**

This is my code for deleting a cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /*Only allow deletion for collection table */
    if(_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"delete ca");
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        CollectedLeaf* collectedLeaf = [collectionFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        LeafletPhotoUploader * leafletPhotoUploader = [[LeafletPhotoUploader alloc] init];
        leafletPhotoUploader.collectedLeaf = collectedLeaf;

        if([LeafletUserRegistration isUserRegistered]) {
            [leafletPhotoUploader deleteCollectedLeaf:collectedLeaf delegate:self];
        }


        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [collectionFetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[collectionFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) //this causes breakpoint
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
            if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0)
            {
                for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors)
                {
                    NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
            }
        }
    }

    }

}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [_table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            NSLog(@"delete called");
            [_table beginUpdates];
            [_table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [_table endUpdates];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[_table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSLog(@"fetched update");
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [_table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [_table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```